# How to add public subnets to a security group?

Tags: aws-cdk

I wrote this code to add public subnets of VPC to a rdsSecurityGroup.

```
for publicSubnet in self.vpc.public_subnets:
    self.rdsSecurityGroup.add_ingress_rule(peer=publicSubnet,
                                           connection=ec2.Port.tcp(3306))
```

But I got this error:

```
jsii.errors.JSIIError: peer.toIngressRuleConfig is not a function
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Have a look at the explanation on using [`remoteRule`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-ec2.SecurityGroup.html#add-wbr-ingress-wbr-rulepeer-connection-description-remoterule). This attribute might be needed based on your use case. remoteRule controls where the Rule object is created if the peer is also a securityGroup and they are in different stack. If false (default) the rule object is created under the current SecurityGroup object. If true and the peer is also a SecurityGroup, the rule object is created under the remote SecurityGroup object.

Comment: Above comment might not be relevant to your problem, that was just my hunch. The public subnets are part of the current CDK stack? If you have imported the VPC, subnets and security Group then your approach might not work. When you import a resource using `fromLookup`, in case of security group you will have `ISecurityGroup` instead of `IPeer`. Therefore, the function `toIngressRuleConfig()` will not be available.

Comment: The public subnets are created using ec2.Vpc by passing subnet_configuration as the parameter. The public subnets are part of the  current CDK stack.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-security-groups.html#security-group-rules, the source/destination of the security group rule can be one of

- IP address (range)
- Security group
- AWS service prefix

Based on above, you would need to lookup CIDR blocks of your public subnets and add those as your sources for ingress rules. However, it looks like lookup of CIDR blocks of vpc/subnets is not so easy at the moment - https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/2232. You  would need to either remember your CIDR blocks in the code if you are creating the subnets, or have CIDR blocks as a constans in your code in case you are using existing VPC and subnets.

Alternative, perhaps more suitable and convenient is to use security groups as a source for your rules. Add all resources in your public subnets to security groups and manage security group rules based on those.